# Consistent packet loss

Tags: packet-loss

I have been facing packet loss for the last two months, on CSGO and Valorant. I have tried everything to fix it, which is reinstalling my network drivers, resetting my network adapter to the factory version, winsock resets and DNS flushes, etc. I have a fiber optic wireless connection, and a windows 11 HP Pavillion gaming laptop. The router is quite far from where I keep my laptop, so I am unable to use an ethernet cable. The network diagnostics on the games show a consistent packet loss, but when I checked the packet loss using the ping command on cmd, it shows a 0% packet loss (I kept sending packets till I manually aborted the command.). Can I thus conclude that it is a hardware problem, that my network adapter is faulty? What else can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: As it's a laptop, can you temporarily relocate to be A) closer to the WiFi access point / router, and B) physically connected by cable? I'd wager this is a long-range WiFi issure over anything else. What are the results from running `ping`? (Are they consistently low, high, or spiky?)

Comment: After running ping, the most frequent latency is 7 ms, and once in a while it spikes to around 160. But after I did the test it showed a 0 packet loss.

Answer (score 1):

`I have a fiber optic wireless connection` - well, that is a contradiction for starters.

I conclude it is likely to be a wireless connection to a router that has fiber attached to it.

Now [mtr](https://www.google.se/search?q=my%20traceroute) (my traceroute) will allow you to continually "ping" a server on  the outside, and see statistics for that.

"[Wifi analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en)" (Andoid app) will also tell you a lot about your wifi; signal strength at a specific location for starters, and also if you have neighbors that uses the same channel(s).

An finally; expecting reliable high through on a wifi connection that has some distance to the wifi access point, might actually be futile. Maybe look into how to move the router closer, or if a Wifi extender could be installed.

Comment: You're right, it's a fiber optic connection connected to a wireless wifi router. However, my router has been away from my laptop for quite a while now, and this problem started very recently. There was never a packet loss before. I will try out the things you said, though. Thanks!

Comment: Well, a (new) neighbor or one "old" began to use wifi more frequently?

Answer (score 0):

In realtime environments (like games, VoIP, etc...), packets that arrive late will be dropped - they're of no use, things have moved on since they were sent, and this is especially true if another packet was sent ***after*** it, but arrived ***before*** it. Out of order packets in these applications are often simply discarded, and may well be counted as dropped or lost in any reported stats.

In a non-realtime environment (e.g: ICMP ping, web browsing, buffered video playback, etc...) late packets will instead degrade the percieved experience.

This can almost be used as a "*UDP vs. TCP*" case study, though there are of course caveats.

---

> the most frequent latency is 7 ms, and once in a while it spikes to around 160

Relatively speaking, 160 ms is a *long time* - CSGO's default command rate is `64` (see [`cl_cmdrate`](https://totalcsgo.com/commands/clcmdrate) and [`sv_mincmdrate`](https://totalcsgo.com/commands/svmincmdrate)). This means both the client and server will send 64 updates per second, or once every ~15.6 ms.

160 ms spans more than 10 updates (or "*ticks*"), and it's worse if you're connected to a "*high performance*" server with a higher tick rate.

Given the intricacies of the internet, it's possible for packets to arrive out of order... but it's also possible for this to happen at the WiFi link - for example due to congestion and retransmission, or even poor signal strength and subsequent retransmission.

---

> I have been facing packet loss for the last two months

> The router is quite far from where I keep my laptop, so I am unable to use an ethernet cable.

You've already told us that the router is quite far from your computer, but you could try changing the WiFi channel or using improved antennas... ultimately, this is one of the reasons people avoid WiFi for things like games.

The environment could have changed due to a new computer, IoT gadget, neighbour, etc... it's impossible to say what the cause is, but given your description, I'd suggest not using WiFi would be a good step - even if it's a one-time test to prove it out.

---

Unfortunately I'm not aware of a good and simple test for "*out of order packets*", and I wouldn't expect any web-based test to be able to offer you this insight, as they'll be using HTTPS (thus TCP), and such details will be invisible to them. If you're up for it, you could dive in and try using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to prove / disprove this hypothesis.

As you're games-oriented, I'd suggest you consider anything over ~20ms to be a timeout next time you run `ping -t ...`.